FreeGLUT necessary for Asymptote?
I use Asymptote. Upon compiling, I stumble across such error:
asy: error while loading shared libraries: libglut.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

After some googling, libglut.so.3 is part of freeglut3, a graphics library that Asymptote uses. Apparently, TeXLive doesn't include it.
Since I don't want to create my own Docker image, if possible, is there a way to deactivate FreeGLUT (ideally via some command line option or in Asymptote code as a settings attribute)? What is it roughly used for in Asymptote, and is it really necessary?

Background: I'm trying to automate compilation via Gitlab CI/CD, i.e. every time I push, a script is executed that compiles my LaTeX code. I use the official TeXLive Docker image for that purpose. The reason I don't want to install FreeGLUT is that otherwise, I'd need to create a new custom Docker image.

On my system - for both TL's asy and the regular asy - the binary is dynamically linked to libglut.so. If asy can do without it, you'd need a binary compiled without. Please change 'official TeXLive Docker image' to 'official Docker TeX Live image'. The link you give is to Docker, so I'm assuming it is their image - not TeX Live's. This is important, especially if the image is providing binaries which cannot work without making a different image.

@cfr Interesting. The term "TeXLive Docker image" is traight up the title of the README, although I agree that it is a TeXLive image, not a Docker one. The image is actually created by Island of TeX, made official in TUGboat 40 (2019), so I assume that it is semi-official.

Hmm. Also interesting. I don't know if that makes it official TeX Live or not, but it does provide some kind of sanction ;).

@cfr Where did you get TeXLive from? Maybe one of the precompiled binaries from your pkg manager on Linux?

From https://tug.org/texlive/. I don't use my distro's packages for TeX Live - only upstream. That's why I have e.g. two asy: one in /usr/local/texlive/bin and one in /usr/bin.

I don't see any mention of a docker image there or under 'other methods', unless I've missed it, which makes me think it's not an image of TeX Live's. If it was, I'd suggest raising the issue on the mailing list, but, if it's not, you'd want to raise it with Island of TeX, I guess?

Don't know if https://github.com/TeX-Live/tl-build-docker-action is useful. This is linked from TeX Live's official pages. They say it is used for 'some of [their] automated builds'.

"TeX Live", i.e., Norbert/Siep/Akira/me/etc., don't create any Docker images.
We are aware of the Island of TeX images. I believe they are useful for many people, which is great, but they are created by Paulo/Ben/others on the island, not by upstream TeX Live.

cfr's answer is correct: if you want an asy binary without libglut, you'll have to compile your own. The instructions I wrote for compiling asy are at https://tug.org/texlive/build.html#asymptote. You'll want to add --disable-gl, as mentioned there. We (TL) don't disable it by default because the primary asy author/maintainer (John Bowman) strongly recommended gl support be included.
